# No response from HTTP GET code when put in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to write an app that involves an activity that sends a GET request to a webpage, gets the code as a response and then parses it for one specific string (the winner's name). This works just fine when I run it as a stand-alone Java code on my terminal. Putting it into an Android activity though yields no results: neither success nor errors.

Given below is the code of the MainActivity:

```
package com.projects.appbrewers.swaghrwtracker;

package com.example.myprojects.myapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    String url = "<some URL here>";
    String currentWinnerName = "";

    TextView currentWinnerLabel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        currentWinnerLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.currentWinnerLabel);
        currentWinnerLabel.setText("Finding...");
        try
        {
            checkCurrentWinner();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //print e.getMessage() to log
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //HTTP GET Request to Swagbucks HRW iframe page
    public void checkCurrentWinner() throws Exception
    {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if(responseCode == 200)
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // strip out your required data with a regex
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*<div id=\"randomWinnerName\">([a-z0-9]*)</div>.*");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response.toString());

            if (matcher.find())
            {
                currentWinnerName = matcher.group(1);
                currentWinnerLabel.setText(currentWinnerName);
            }
            else
                currentWinnerLabel.setText("Not Found!");
        }
        else
            currentWinnerLabel.setText("ERROR!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing network operations on the UI thread. Use an `AsyncTask`

Comment: Can you please show me how to use AsyncTask in this case?

Comment: Use the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options to do it:
 1. Use an `AsyncTask` to perform the HTTP GET operation

```
private class CheckUsernameFromUrlTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {
     protected String doInBackground(URL... urlToGetTheUsername) {
         String usernameFromHttpGetMethod = null;
         // code to make (similar to your checkCurrentWinner method)
         //   1. HTTP GET request
         //   2. Extract username (incl. error handling)
         return usernameFromHttpGetMethod;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         // ignore for now, unless you want to show the progress blocking UI
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         // back in the UI thread. Perform all view operations
         // Handle exceptions by saving the exception thrown in 
         // doInBackground method as an instance variable of this class or
         // changing the return object to be a custom object containing
         // username and exception.
         String labelText = result == null ? "Not Found!" : result;
         currentWinnerLabel.setText(labelText );
     }
 }
```

Then to use the AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // ...
   new CheckUsernameFromUrlTask ().execute(url1, url2, url3);
}
```

2. Use the [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) library. The library uses a Callback object to get the request asynchronously via a background thread, so you don't have to write code for an AsyncTask. See the documentation for retrofit for examples.

Comment: This helps! But what are the values for url1, url2 and url3?

Comment: Also, I'm guessing I can use onPostExecute to set the player's name in the TextView but how do I pass this in 'result'. Am I to call onPostExecute in doInBackground() ?

Comment: url1, url2 etc are the inputs to the doInBackground method. If you always have a single method, you can hardcode it within CheckUsernameFromUrlTask class, otherwise can pass it in as an input. It gives you that flexibility.

The output of the doInBackground method is the same as the input for the onPostExecute method (Also the 3rd/last typed value for AsyncTask). You can make it to be any object to pass in whatever result you want.

Answer (score 1):

you need to run this in Separate thread not in UI thread. Use AsyncTask to execute checkCurrentWinner()

```
private class CheckCurrentWinner extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String> {

    public CheckCurrentWinner(String url) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

            }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        try {
           checkCurrentWinner();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
```

}

in 'onPostExecute()' you can change currentWinnerLabel

you can call this class using new CheckCurrentWinner().execute()

Comment: Ohk I have no idea how to use this thread. Can you please provide the required code in your answer?

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out!

Comment: What does 'Integer...' mean? Sorry for the noob question but some other answer uses the same terminology. Also, do I have to pass the winner's name to onPostExecute as 'result' from doInBackground?

Comment: then change it to String if you want to pass Name

Comment: I meant I don't understand the '...' notation? Also, I don't understand what function is invoked when you call CheckCurrentWinner().execute(). Is doInBackground automatically invoked?

Comment: '....' notation means it accepts array of Integers. when execute() is called first onpreExecute() is called....then after finishing that onBackground is called and later onPostexecute

Comment: Alright, that explains a lot! So should I just use a class variable instead that can be set by onBackground and then simple used by onPastExecute to set the TextView instead of trying to use the String result parameter?

Comment: you can use class variables

Comment: Final question: how can I access the TextView resource in this external class? Or can this class's execute() be used to return a String value that can be used to set the value of the TextView in MainActivity? If yes, how?

Comment: you can initialize textview in onPreexecute and update it in onPostexecute

Comment: or add this class as inner class of activity. you can access textview from here

Answer (score 0):

I am certain that there will be a NetworkOnMainThread Exception thrown here, and is not like what you said that no errors occured. So, you just have to put that in a separate thread like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         try
        {
            checkCurrentWinner();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //print e.getMessage() to log
        }
    }
}).start();
```